# How to install the latest (unstable) version of libglm-dev?

Tags: apt

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

What is the right way to install an unstable/development version of a package with [apt](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/apt.8.html)? In my case, libglm-dev 0.9.9.7: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glm/0.9.9.7+ds-1

At the time of writing, the version installed by `apt install libglm-dev` is 0.9.9.0.

Comment: That version is currently in the Ubuntu 20.04 repositories. One safe way is to boot a 20.04 LiveUSB. Another safe way is to install 20.04 in a Virtual Machine.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize that, thanks. I edited my question to clarify which Ubuntu version I'm using. I have a fairly involved build setup in 18.04, I just realized that the glm version that apt installs by default is slightly too old. Is my only option to manually install the right version of libglm-dev then?

Comment: You can try manually downloading the package from launchpad, and installing with apt. Doing so is possible, but unsupported, so do a backup first, and record your output just in case it does something unexpected and spectacular. It likely will work just fine for folks who take basic precautions.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/apt.html is a useful general guide to apt